# Ruby/Rails if/else case statement

Tags: ruby

I have the following if else statement in a lib method:

```
begin
    url                  = URI.parse("url"+ product )
    @response            = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)
    url2                 = URI.parse("url" + product)
    @response1           = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url2).body)

    if @response != nil
        @url                 = @response["product"]["url"]
        image_url1           = @response["product"]["image_url"]
        @title               = @response["product"]["title"] 

    else
        @url                 = @response1["ProductUrl"]
        @image_url           = @response1["ImagePath"]  
        @title               = @response1["ProductName"]
    end
  rescue 
     next 
end
```

Currently this method is only checking url and @response, and is simply skipping if @response = nil. How do I check if @response is nil, and if so, use url2 and @response1 and save the variables returned from that response. If @response is not nil, save the variables returned from @respoonse.

@response and @response1 are different APIs

Comment: `URI.parse("url+ product )` You appear to have a syntax error...

Comment: What's the difference between url and url2, and @response and @response1?

Comment: I believe that the issue is that `JSON.parse` never returns nil.  I can't find that in the documentation, but I can't get it to return nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  The key is that to check for nil, use @response.nil?  Another problem is see is that you get the same url if it fails the first time - not sure why you would ask for the same url again and treat it differently if it failed the first time.

```
begin
  url = URI.parse("url+ product )
  @response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)

  if !@response.nil?
    @url = @response["product"]["walmart_canonical_url"]
    @image_url = @response["product"]["image_url"]
    @title = @response["product"]["title"] 
  else
    url = URI.parse("url" + product)
    @response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url2).body)
    @url = @response["ProductUrl"]
    @image_url = @response["ImagePath"]  
    @title = @response["ProductName"]
  end

rescue
  next
end
```